# Adding default value in simpledialog.askstring using tkinter in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a simple textbox using tkinter. Below is the code I am trying to use.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tk.Tk() # Create an instance of tkinter

start_date = simpledialog.askstring(title = "Test Title",
                                    prompt = "Entire Start Date in MM/DD/YYYY format:")
```

Below is the output I am getting as expected.

[image]

My question is, how do I populate a default value in the empty slot by default, as shown below?

[image]

In R, I can easily do this using the below command.

```
start_date <- winDialogString("Entire Start Date in MM/DD/YYYY format:", "01/31/2018")
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you read [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-entry-dialogs.htm)? You can provide `initialvalue` as option like

`simpledialog.askstring(title = "Test Title", prompt = "Entire Start Date in MM/DD/YYYY format:", initialvalue="whateveryouwant")`

Comment: Thank you @Da_Pz! Just what I was looking for!

Comment: The link no longer works

Comment: New link [here](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/tkinter-entry-dialogs.htm).